# How to get Number of executors and Number of tasks per executors programmatically in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

For some reason, I want to create as many partitions as the number of executors * number of tasks. This is what I'll pass to the second parameter of `sc.parallelize`. Now my question is, can I programmatically get the number of executors and number of tasks per executor in Spark.